# How to know if app is using softkey pad or hardware key pad?

Tags: java, android

Are there any API that helps the app to know if it is getting key events from hardware keypad or softkey pad?

Thanks & Best Regards

Sudhakar Chavali

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

There are flags like `FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD`, `FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY` and others.